# How to synchronize a git repository with a sub directory of another repository

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm working on a big application that contains a **src/** directory and I'd like to share only this **src/** directory.

So, I'd like to push periodically this **src/** directory to another repository (and keep the tags and branches that were made and contains changes made on files inside the **src/** ).

So far, I've done the following:

```
git clone MyBigProject /tmp/foo
cd /tmp/foo

# I want to share the master and 1.0, 1.1, 2.0,... branches
REMOTE_BRANCHES=`git branch -r | tr -d " " | grep "^origin/[0-9]\.[0-9]$"`
for BRANCH in $REMOTE_BRANCHES; do
    # So I need to track them locally in order to rewrite them
    git checkout --track $BRANCH
done

git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf `ls -1 | grep -v src`' --prune-empty -- --all

git push MySharedRepo --all
git push MySharedRepo --tags
```

Problem is that `filter-branch` will create new commit hashes, thus pushing to the `MySharedRepo` brings a lot of conflicts. It would also mean that it will corrupt all the users references each time I will push the shared repositories.

I'd like to point that `MySharedRepo` is be a READ-ONLY repository.

I've been searching around for the past couple of days without finding the correct solution for this problem, so thanks in advance if you can help me resolving it!

Answer (score 0):

Sharing only the subdirectory by means of filter-branch is the right path. Optimally, if the `src` directory can exist on its own, the main (parent) repository may benefit from containing the `filter-branch` repository as a submodule. This achieves the following:

1. Provides separate repositories for the `src` contents and the parent project.
2. Supports control of read/read+write access to `src` as a repository 
   (if shared on a central repository like https://github.com).
3. Eliminates repeated `git filter-branch` efforts each time commits on `src` need sharing